# How to remove multiple elements from multidimensional array with filter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

We can filter out a single value from an array with the `filter` function like this:

```
var possi = [
        ['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6'], ['7','8','9'], ['1','4','7'], 
        ['2','5','8'], ['3','6','9'], ['1','5','9'], ['3','5','7']
    ];

var remove = '1';

possi = possi.filter(function(p){
    return p.indexOf(remove) === -1;
});
```

The result is:

```
[ [ '4', '5', '6' ],
  [ '7', '8', '9' ],
  [ '2', '5', '8' ],
  [ '3', '6', '9' ],
  [ '3', '5', '7' ] ]
```

But if we have multiple elements to remove, that is, if we have:

```
var remove = ['1', '6'];
```

How can we check if each `remove` element exists in `possi` and filter out the matching `possi` element?

Also, do any other functions such as `map` or `reduce` be a better solution in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all arrays in `possi` which match any element of array `remove`, you could combine [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var possi = [
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['4', '5', '6'],
  ['7', '8', '9'],
  ['1', '4', '7'],
  ['2', '5', '8'],
  ['3', '6', '9'],
  ['1', '5', '9'],
  ['3', '5', '7']
];

var remove = ['1', '6'];

possi = possi.filter(function(p) {
  return !p.some(function(v) {
    return remove.indexOf(v) !== -1;
  });
});

console.log(possi);
```

The result is:

```
[
  ['7', '8', '9'],
  ['2', '5', '8'],
  ['3', '5', '7']
]
```

Comment: And, to expand, if you want to remove the arrays that have all the elements in `remove` (1 AND 6, not 1 OR 6) you can use `.every` instead of `some`.